# How can I log events in dash to debug my dash app?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I want to know, how I can debug my dash app. I had the idea to log some information on the state of variables in the debug popup on the right, that shows when debug mode is on.
Is there a way to do so? Or are there any tips on how to debug dash apps?
I have one rather complicated callback and cannot figure out the problem. I can always use `print` to write to the shell log.

[Screenshot to show, which debug window is mentioned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ja7r.png)

Comment: I suggest sharing the code and error message, and we can help, if you do not mind.

Comment: Please [do not post images of code or errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question) - 
see the answer in the link on why images can hinder others helping you.

Comment: There is no code in the image and I don’t want help on my specific bug, I asked about the debug functionality of dash. I just use print then to debug, like them old days